# MySQL Select, subqueries, and more

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I am having problems with a 'complicated' select. I have different tables (one per year), and they look like:

Last year:

```
ShortName  LongName  Year
Nam1       Name One  2016
Nam2       Name Two  2016
...
Namn       Name N    2016
```

Year 2015

```
ShortName  LongName       Year
Nam1       Name AltOne    2015
Nam4       Name AltFour   2015
...
Namn       Name AltN      2015
```

That is, when an individual appears in two (or more) years, the observations have the same ShortName, but the LongName can be different every year. The individuals might (or might not) be repeated through the years.

I want to select the most recent LongName for all individuals in all tables. I mean, the individual Nam1 appears in 2016 and in 2015. I want to select her last LongName available, which is 'Name One'. The same applies to Nam2.

Nam4 does NOT appear in 2016, but it does in 2015, so I want to select 'Name AltFour'.

The final select would be:

```
ShortName    LongName      Year
Nam1         Name One      2016
Nam2         Name Two      2016
Nam4         Name AltFour  2015
Namn         Name N        2016
```

I have tables from 2016 to 2013. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: First rule of databases, do not split a table in 4 different tables for 4 years. Second rule of databases, do not split a table in 4 different tables for 4 years. You can kinda fix your mistake, apart from it being slow due to not using nice indexes, by using a `union all` and then query it as if it would be just one table: `select * from (select * from table1 union all select * from table2 union all ...) a where not exists (select * from (select * from table1 union all select * from table2 union all ...) a1 where a1.Shortname = a.Shortname and a.Year < a1.Year)`. Or put it back into 1 table.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The reason why I have different tables is that I have different variables for each year, apart from the relevant ones to this problem.

Comment: Javi, you probably would have been better off creating tables for the varying variable sets that are linked to the "years" table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
-- Create a temporary singular table of the shared fields.
-- Ideally, the actual table probably should've looked something like this.
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmpAll;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmpAll`
SELECT ShortName, LongName, `Year` FROM table2016
UNION SELECT ShortName, LongName, `Year` FROM table2015
UNION SELECT ShortName, LongName, `Year` FROM table2014
UNION SELECT ShortName, LongName, `Year` FROM table2013
;

-- Find the most recent years for each name.
-- This could have just been a subquery of the next/last query; but...
-- MySQL does not support queries that reference a TEMPORARY table more than once.
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmpRecents;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmpRecents`
SELECT Shortname, MAX(`Year`) AS `Year` 
FROM tmpAll
GROUP BY ShortName
;

-- Get the tmpAll records for the most recent year of each ShortName
SELECT tmpAll.*
FROM tmpAll INNER JOIN `tmp` USING (ShortName, `Year`)
;

-- You can DROP the temporary tables here, or 
-- they will just go away when the connection is closed.
```

If it is slow, you can add a (`ShortName`, `Year`) index to the temporary tables.